# Iphone producer consumer local network with Mac

Tags: iphone, networking, local

i am searching for a way to connect to a Mac from an iPhone in order to write/read a file and synchronize that, like a producer-consumer.

My idea is to create a file in the Mac, and write and read from the iPhone, may be one iPhone app to write and another to read.

thanks in advance, if anyone has a better idea... just tell me about it.

Answer (score 0):

id say the most ideal way to accomplish this is via the Bonjour protocol.

Here is a great article on the subject, http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/